# How can I set the region in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, system-settings, plist

I want to change the Region via Terminal.
How can I do this ?

Ideally it would use a command (/usr/bin or sbin) or modify a plist ([plistbuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html)).

I'd love to avoid using osascript (AppleScript)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The region is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences`, as the second part of the **AppleLocale** variable.  Some examples of the AppleLocale variable:

- **en_US** *system language set to English, region set to US*
- **ja_JP** *system language set to Japanese, region set to Japan*
- **en_DE** *system language set to English, region set to Germany*

You can get more info from [Apple's Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html), which also has links to the ISO 639-2 codes that can be used.